# Sql column alias not working in Ebeans rawsql

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean

I am facing strange issue with raw SQLs, and I need some help to figure out the best way to fix it. I could, of course, add the columnMappings, but I want to make sure it's not because I am doing something wrong.

- Play Framework APP
- Ebeans ORM
- Postgresql 9.,4

Executing the following RawSQL against a Postgresql database fails if I don't define columnMappings, although I have an alias defined:

```
    String sql
            = "  Select date_trunc('day', end_time) as theDate,  "
            + "  count(*) as value "
            + "  From ebay_item "
            + "  group by date_trunc('day', end_time) ";

    RawSql rawSql =
            RawSqlBuilder
                    .parse(sql)
                    .create();
```

Error:

016-03-25 12:05:15,303 ERROR m.c.a.e.s.p.SimpleDBPromiseService  - Error executing named query
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Property [dateTrunc('day'] not found on models.com.abiesolano.ebay.sqlpojos.RangedDateCounter

If I switch to an H2 database:

```
    String sql
            = " SELECT trunc(end_time) as theDate, "
            + "  count(*) as value "
            + "  From ebay_item "
            + "  Group by trunc(end_time)";

    RawSql rawSql =
            RawSqlBuilder
                    .parse(sql)
                    .create();
```

it works no problems.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mysql likes to group or order by functions, you should use your alias "theDate" instead.

Note that if you're mapping to a bean object, the alias must be a @Transient property of your bean to be mapped by Ebean (otherwise, you'll get an unknown property error).